# Why would variable j need assignment on every iteration for my javascript bruteforce solution to twoSum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

So I solved the twoSum problem which you can find here: [twoSum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) and I know there are better and more efficient solutions but for this one, I am just trying to understand why I get an empty array unless I reassign variable j inside the while loop. See code below. When I tried solving it by assigning j outside of the loop it doesn't work. See code comments.

My halfway answer/initial thought was that by assigning j's value outside of the loop its doing a direct assignment by value which means its value doesn't change since the interpreter only runs top to bottom and doesn't actually go back to check. So this would mean that if j were to be assigned by reference this problem would not occur?? I don't know if I'm on the right track

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
  let indecesArr = [];
  let i = 0;
  //j declaration without assignment
  let j;
  //let j = i + 1; //this will cause return to be empty array
  

  while (i < nums.length) {\
    //j's value has to be reassigned here otherwise return is an empty [] array
      j = i + 1;
    while (j < nums.length) {
      if (nums[i] + nums[j] === target) {
        indecesArr.push(i, j);
      }
      j++;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return indecesArr;
};

console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 4], 6)); //output [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of j in the inner while loop.

So when i =0 meaning nums[i] = 3 then j increments till the very end as their is no matching pair.
So next time when i = 1 & so on j has already traversed till the end of the array. Code inside the second loop never executes from i=1,hence no matching pair